# Not able to update a variable if a string of characters found within a string

Tags: python

I am trying to update a variable called `status` using for loop iteration

```
status = 'The device1 is present'

devices = ['device1', 'device2', 'device3']

for device in devices:
    if device not in status:
        status = 'fine'

print(status)
```

I am getting the output `'fine'`, instead of `'The device1 is present'`.

Tried several ways but unable to solve this.

Comment: `device3 no in status = True` That explains why status is fine.

Comment: Why did you think you'd get any output *other* than `'fine'`? And why are you changing the thing you want to test?

Comment: @DanielMesejo I think you mean `'device2' not in status`, as it's a string and that's the one that gets hits first.

Comment: You can show yourself what's going on if you add `print(device)` in that `if` block.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes you are correct!

Comment: @jonrsharpe what is the way to get the output 'The device1 is present' instead of 'fine' in this case

Comment: It's unclear what your actual logic should be, as you've given no context at all. Are you expecting the value of `status` to be unchanged if *any* of those three values in `devices` is in it?

Comment: Use a break and don't clobber your variable immediately.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have script that logs in into network devices and gets updates the variable status if any interface is down, at the end of script the status variable will have several lines with the names of network devices, I am trying to send a mail using the same script, by checking if the list of network devices is not present in the status variable, for example if the device name is present in the status variable I will get one type of mail, if the device is not present I will get different mail notification

Comment: Please [edit] the question. If nothing else, it seems like a bad idea to use the name `status` for the input *and* the output, as earlier iterations interfere with the overall result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With only one of the items in `devices` that is not present in `status`, it will change to 'fine', and you have two items ('device2' and 'device3') that are not present in `status`, so you will end with `status` with a value of 'fine'.